# Any example of an ideal of a ring which is not commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is often defined as follows:

A subset $I \subseteq R$ is called an ideal if

(1) $(I,+) \leq (R,+)$

(2) $IR \subseteq I$

(3) $RI \subseteq I$

Here a ring does not necessarily contain $1$.

I know then every ideal is a subring, but I would also like to know if $R$ is always commutative or is there a ring which is not commutative but has a non-trivial ideal.

Comment: I suggest you pick your favorite noncommutative ring and try to find an ideal in it (and I really, really hope no one gives you an example before you find one yourself!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your comment, I will try to find one myself using the ring of $n \times n$ matrices of integers.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Found it, for $2 \times 2$ matrices of real numbers, the set of matrices of which first column elements are zero is an ideal of the upper triangular matrices set over the real numbers.

Comment: Good try! But that ring of matrices is simple: it does not have any non-trivial proper ideals. What you found is a *left* (or *right*) ideal, so that only one of (2) or (3) holds.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The set of matrices with zero first column *is* an ideal of the ring of upper triangular $2\times2$ matrices. James's example is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, *most* noncommutative rings have nontrivial ideals.

For example, you can take $End(V_k)$ where $k$ is a field and $V$ is an infinite dimensional $k$ vector space. This has a nontrivial ideal consisting of tranformations with finite dimensional images.

Here are [a bunch of examples](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?lacks=1&lacks=7) of rings that aren't commutative but also have nontrivial ideals.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and thank you again for the nice database website, I greatly appreciate it.